# Heroku Java "JVM Common app detected" and not "Executing Maven"

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku

I struggled to figure out this issue myself and Heroku support is only for non-free accounts. They direct me to post it as a question ... but I now know the answer. Hoping that posting it here helps someone in the future.

I had used the Heroku Maven plugin at first because I thought it would be neat to just click the run configuration in my IDE and have it do the deployment. However, I then noticed the downside of it uploading the entire large deployment jar each time. This wasn't the effect that I wanted. So, then I switched to using git. However, it was not doing the maven build on the server when I did the "git push". I went through all of their examples and went round and round through so many guesses. Then I finally got a little smarter and copied my app code into a new folder and created a new heroku app directly from it. And it worked. It did the maven build. I noticed that what it was saying right before when it was working was "Java app detected" whereas when the original wasn't working it was saying "JVM Common app detected".

Answer (score 1):

What happened is that when I first deployed using the heroku maven plugin, it added a "JVM buildpack" automatically. After that buildpack was added, even going the git route would not make it act like a normal "heroku/java" buildpack. All I had to do (after trying things for hours), was just go into my app's settings and delete the JVM buildpack that was there. Then when I did another "git push heroku master", it automatically re-configured it with "heroku/java", it had "Java app detected", it ran Maven, and I was in business.

What a struggle for one click in my settings! I hope someone else doesn't have to struggle the same way I did.